About Solana Instruction Decode Levels
I got confused about PartiallyDecodedInstruction and ParsedInstruction.
When fetching a transaction use getTransaction RPC call and load them using solana-transaction-status crate, we can see that the vec<Instruction> field of meta->InnerInstruction is two enums:
pub enum UiParsedInstruction {
    Parsed(ParsedInstruction),
    PartiallyDecoded(UiPartiallyDecodedInstruction),
}

I am confused why there should be two enums for an instruction. There's no explanation on rpc docs or crate docs.
Thank you!

Did you manage to find an answer to this?
